# Using inline css to display data URI images in IE8 or lower

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer-8, base64

I'm trying to display base64 encoded images as explained in this [link](http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/).
 My question is, instead of using url's for css,

```
*background-image: url(mhtml:http://phpied.com/mhtml.css!somestring);
```

I want to display them without providing any url's. By url, I mean "http://phpied.com/mhtml.css", it looks like I need to create a CSS file for base64 images.

Can anyone tell me how we can display image in IE8 or less without creating a new CSS file?

Comment: Set `max-width` css style depending upon your image size.

Comment: @Ranjith, I'm not trying to adjust my image size, my images are data uri's and I want to use them in IE7, IE8 which does not support data URI directly. So, I thought of using mhtml described in the link I mentioned in my post. My doubt is they are using an url of a css file for 'background' property in the example, but I want to use inline style for image tag.

Comment: See lower version of `IE8` doesn't support `data URI`, but in IE8 you can directly give your data URI in `src="..."` using `img` tag.

Comment: yes, they support only upto 32KB, this is not an ideal solution, so I'm trying to use mhtml to display images greater than 32KB

Comment: I'm also struggling to find the solution.. Why do you wants to only in  `img` tag?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any other way to render data uri's of size greater that 32KB in IE8? One way I googled is mhtml, now checking how it works

Comment: Better to use `CSS classes`. It simple. Did you face issues on that?

Comment: Yes, only red cross marks are displayed in IE8 browser instead of image. If you are using IE9 or higher changing browser mode will display images in IE8, IE7 but not in an IE8 browser.